# Python selenium refresh if wait more than 10s

Tags: python, selenium, page-refresh

```
from selenium import webdriver    
driver=webdriver.Firefox() 
driver.get(url)
```

Sometimes the webdriver is stuck on a file or response and the page is never full-loaded so the line

```
driver.get(url)
```

is never finished. But I already got enough source code to run the rest of my code. I am wondering how can I bypass or refresh the page if the page is not full-loaded in 10 seconds.

I have tried

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException    
driver=webdriver.Firefox() 
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
while True:
    try:
        driver.get(url)
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Timeout, retrying...")
        continue
    else:
        break
```

but the line

```
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
```

always gives me following error

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 727, in set_page_load_timeout
'pageLoad': int(float(time_to_wait) * 1000)})
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 238, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 193, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message:
```

This is nothing after Message:. I can't identify the type of error. It's weird that my laptop can't run

```
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
```

My next step is to click a button on the page, but that button doesn't always exist even after full-loaded. Thus I can't use explicit wait.

Thanks

Comment: Can you update the stack trace to include whatever is after "Message:"? `WebDriverException` is the generic base exception for selenium and can be raised for many different reasons.

Comment: There is nothing after Message: I don't know what type of error it is.

Comment: @JimmyLee it's not an good idea, however why not you catch this generic webdriver exception as well ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(In your code snippet you don't define URL, but I'll assume URL is defined somewhere in your actual code.)

You could combine the [retry](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/retry) and [timeout-decorator](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/timeout-decorator) packages for this:

```
from retry import retry
from timeout_decorator import timeout, TimeoutError
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException    

@retry(TimeoutError, tries=3)
@timeout(10)
def get_with_retry(driver, url):
    driver.get(url)


def main():
    url = "http://something.foo"

    driver=webdriver.Firefox() 
    try:
        get_with_retry(driver, url)
        foo(driver) # do whatever it is you need to do
    finally:
        driver.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Note that you would need to either not set `driver.set_page_load_timeout` to anything, or set it to something higher than 10 seconds.