# how to stop selenium page loading?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

hi when i attempt to load a page using selenium i get this error `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Timeout loading page after 300000ms`
how do i change this to raise this exception after 10 sec? 
i have tried this so fare but nothing works:

```
firefoxProfile.set_preference("network.http.connection-timeout", 10)
firefoxProfile.set_preference("http.response.timeout", 10)
firefoxProfile.set_preference("dom.max_script_run_time", 10)
```

and

```
browser.set_timeout("30")
```

gives me:

```
AttributeError: 'FirefoxProfile' object has no attribute 'set_timeout'
```

Comment: Can you consider updating us your business case, why you want to stop page loading Midway? The elements may not load completely in the HTML DOM. You may not able to work with the elements. Let me know your thoughts. Thanks

Comment: Check if the proxy server is working and at optimal speed, and some pages have infinite loading time as they just keep loading js elements and keep the rest of the script from executing

Comment: Okay, I am not sure if would be able to provide you with a solution to check proxy server working at optimal speed or not but I can provide a solution to cut down the infinite loading issue. Let me know if you want me to construct an answer for you. Thanks

Comment: Well the way I do it is simply switching to the proxy and trying to connect to it and click and element on the page nothing fancy. That would be really helpful so far the only way I do it is by using pyautogui to click the stop loading, but it is causing me problems.

Comment: As you got a Solution to your Question/Issue, I am holding off my Answer which was constructed for you. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The method to create a timeout for a page to load, in Python, is:

```
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
```

This will throw a TimeoutException whenever the page load takes more than 10 seconds.

Comment: not working i get: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unrecognised timeout: page load

Comment: check if this works for you. If works i will update the answer.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43003924/python-selenium-refresh-if-wait-more-than-10s

Comment: Still not timeout exception

Comment: from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('webdriver.load.strategy', 'unstable')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(5)

Comment: Still the same Unrecognized timeout, am using selenium 3.0.2 btw

Answer (score 0):

Ok the thing is that `set_page_load_timeout()`doesn't work with Firefox but works with the chromedriver. Also I don't get the infinite loading with chromedriver so am switching to that. Thanks for your help.